# Return value being printed first with concurrent futures

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

For some reason, the return value value of this funcion is being printed first:

```
def do_something(t):
    print(f'Sleeping for {t} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(t)
    return 'Done Sleeping...'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        secs = [5,4,3,2,1]
        results = [executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())
```

From what I've seen online, even if I use `as_completed()`, the return value is always printed after the function finished. This code even comes from a YouTube video where it seems to be working normally.

Edit:

What I would expect to be printed out from this code would be

```
Sleeping for 1 second(s)...
Sleeping for 2 second(s)...
Sleeping for 3 second(s)...
Sleeping for 4 second(s)...
Sleeping for 5 second(s)...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
```

What I am getting is the opposite:

```
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping for 1 second(s)...
Sleeping for 2 second(s)...
Sleeping for 3 second(s)...
Sleeping for 4 second(s)...
Sleeping for 5 second(s)...
```

It is still printed out in order of completion, as expected, but `Done Sleeping` is printed out first.

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso&t=1539s&ab_channel=CoreySchafer

Edit 2:

Problem has been fixed. I rewrote the code and found my mistake, so here is the new code:

```
from multiprocessing import *
import time
import concurrent.futures 

def worker(t):
    print(f'Sleeping for {t} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(t)
    return 'Done sleeping'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    secs = [5,4,3,2,1]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        processes = [executor.submit(worker, sec) for sec in secs]

    for x in processes: #the for loop CANNOT be indented used in the Process Pool Executor
        print(x.result())
```

I basically wrongly indented the for loop when printing the results inside the `with ...:`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You say, "... even if I use as_completed(), the return value is always printed after the function finished." If the function you are referring to is the worker function `do_something`, what else could you possibly expect? The `as_completed` will return you futures in the order in which the 5 submitted tasks complete, which must by definition be when `do_something` has returned its result. You can't print a result before that result has been returned. What do you see on Youtube that you don't see when you run your program? You have not specified this not the link to the video.

You did yourself a disservice by having `do_something` return identical strings. To clear up any confusion, let's modify the program slightly so we can better see what is occurring. The return value from your worker function `do_something` will include the passed argument `t`:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_something(t):
    print(f'Sleeping for {t} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(t)
    return f'Done sleeping for {t} seconds.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        secs = [5,4,3,2,1]
        results = [executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())
```

Prints:

```None
Sleeping for 5 second(s)...
Sleeping for 4 second(s)...
Sleeping for 3 second(s)...
Sleeping for 2 second(s)...
Sleeping for 1 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 1 seconds.
Done sleeping for 2 seconds.
Done sleeping for 3 seconds.
Done sleeping for 4 seconds.
Done sleeping for 5 seconds
```

**Discussion**

You are submitting 5 tasks to your multiprocessing pool of N processes where N will be the number of CPU cores you have. The first thing your worker function does is to announce that it will be sleeping for `t` seconds where `t` is the passed argument. Then the function sleeps for `t` seconds. It is not surprising to see the messages 'Sleeping for ... seconds' being printed in task submission order as we do above. This is what I would expect although that is not guaranteed *in theory*. Why?

Let's assume that your pool size `N` is at least 5. Even assuming that all 5 processes can each be assigned its own CPU core to execute in and are running at the same instant in time, one of them has to be the first to be able to pull from the sequential task queue of 5 tasks the first task (whose `t` argument is 5) on that queue (which has to be accessed serially because you cannot have two processes getting the same task from the queue). It makes sense that the first process to be given a task to run will be able to execute its print statement before any other process can. For this not to happen it would have to get interrupted after it took the task from the queue but before it could execute this print statement. This is just not very likely. So all 5 processes will be executing there `print` statements in task-submission in order and that is what we see above. But the first one to complete and return its result will be the task with the smallest `t` value. It will wake up before any other process and return its result, which will be printed by the main process. This will be for `t` == 1, the last task submitted. And again that is what we see.

If we were to assume the extreme case where the pool size `N` were 1, then there would be no other pool process that can process any of the remaining tasks on the task queue. That is, the single pool process must process all 5 tasks in order. You would then see that task completion order is the same as task submission order. That is, the first task to complete will be for `t` value 5, the next for `t` value 4, etc. See the following demo of this phenomenon:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_something(t):
    print(f'Sleeping for {t} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(t)
    return f'Done sleeping for {t} seconds.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Just a single process in the pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
        secs = [5,4,3,2,1]
        results = [executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())
```

Prints:

```None
Sleeping for 5 second(s)...
Sleeping for 4 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 5 seconds.
Sleeping for 3 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 4 seconds.
Sleeping for 2 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 3 seconds.
Sleeping for 1 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 2 seconds.
Done sleeping for 1 seconds.
```

Note that the pool process completes the first task after having slept for 5 seconds returning the result back to the main process. As long as the process still has time remaining on its time slice that it has been given for executing, it will immediately go back and execute the second task and print out 'Sleeping for 4 seconds...' and then goes into a wait state for at least 4 seconds. Meanwhile, the main process is notified of the task completion of the first task and prints the result. But depending on how processes get dispatched it is theoretically possible that we see the main process printing the result of the first task before the pool process can execute it's print statement for the second task. That is, we might see:

```Non
Sleeping for 5 second(s)...
Done sleeping for 5 seconds.
Sleeping for 4 second(s)...
etc.
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. The output you showed is what I expected to get, but it's not what I'm getting.

Comment: Try adding *flush=True* to all your print statements, for example `print(‘some value’, flush=True)` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah, that is another way than what I did to solve it. I like this way since I can see the results coming in as they are finished. Thanks